# PCI questions regarding software

Tags: pci-dss

As a software company who is looking at writing something that could handle debit cards can I self certify my software or do I have to have it tested by a 3rd party company?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the PA-DSS certification process from the PCI Security standards council.

They have information on the standard and certification procedures on their website https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/hardware_software/

Comment: Rory is right. its all in the PA-DSS process. Whether you need to have the app certified depends on how you are going to market/license it. If you are going to offer it as a service then you, as a company would need to be PCI compliant not necessarily the app.